# Does the require_once behavior change when moving from PHP Version 7.0.0RC5 to PHP Version 7.0.11?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, php-7, require-once

I started migrating my applications to PHP7 last year already using the PHP7 release candidate (7.0.0RC5) available at the time. I successfully made all required changes and the apps are all running fine on that version (PHP 7.0.0RC5).

Recently I started testing the code with the latest and greatest PHP-7 version (7.0.11) and everywhere in the code where 'require_once()' is used (not only my code but also in 3rd party libraries) the code breaks with " 'fileA.php'...failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...'fileB.php>' ".

I double-checked and compared all the php.ini settings between the two versions and I am certain there are no differences.

**Question:** Has anything changed between 7.0.0RC5 and now that causes the behavior of require_once to be different? Even just a pointer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect we'd be hearing more about it if something so fundamental was broke or had a behavioural change. Have you done much troubleshooting / analysis of the issue? Have you managed to break the problem down to an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)? If so, can you update your question to include it? Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Adam. I did troubleshoot this all day today and will continue investigating tomorrow. Objective of posting this is to see if this has happened to anybody else. If I am not missing anything (which I do agree is likely given the fundamental nature of this) I will try to put a small example together and post it. Thanks again!